# Why does Queue Uses LinkedList Constructor in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

I was trying to understand the In-built Queue Interface in Java. I understood how to use the class well.

But I cannot Understand why does it use LinkedList Constructor to initiate itself?

why is it needed?
Cannot we implement a queue using an ArrayList?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What `Queue` class? `java.util.Queue` is an interface.

Comment: Wooops! Thanks Edited :D

Comment: I would expect this to be based on the common use of a queue, involving multiple (perhaps many) changes to the elements. ArrayList and Array and such would have more to do adjusting the length and so forth, whereas a linked list is easier to add to and substract from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `LinkedList` implements `Queue`, whereas `ArrayList` does not.

```
Queue<Object> myQueue = new LinkedList<>(); // Works, LinkedList implements Queue
Queue<Object> myQueue = new ArrayList<>(); // Doesn't compile, ArrayList doesn't implement queue
```

Now, if you so wished, you could write a new class implementing Queue, and using an ArrayList as its backing container, but I don't see the appeal since you can already initialize a LinkedList from an ArrayList. Arguably, there could be some performance on the `List` methods (if you implemented it too) but there would be little to none on the `Queue` methods.

Sources:
Javadoc for [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)